# Angular 4 radio button issue

Tags: forms, angular

I'm trying to create a list of radio buttons from categories.
The categories is an array of objects like this:

```
[
    {
        _id: '58cfb65b2ad6426beec93231'
        label: 'Category name',
        checked: true
    }, {
        _id: '58cfb65b2ad6426beec93232'
        label: 'Category name 2',
        checked: false
    }
]
```

Now I try to render a list of radio buttons and want to set checked by the checked value.

```
<label *ngFor="let cat of categories">
    <input 
       type="radio" 
       name="category" 
       [checked]="cat.checked" 
       [(ngModel)]="selectedCategory" 
       [value]="cat._id"/>
    {{ cat.label[lang.code] }}
</label>
```

The radio buttons all come up unchecked and selectedCategory is undefined. When I submit the form and check the values it also comes out undefined... Anyone knows what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `[(ngModel)]`, you are telling Angular to do *two-way databinding*.

Two-way means from code to markup and vice versa. So, when Angular creates the radiobuttons (markup), it will check whether your AppComponent has a `selectedCategory` property and, if so, it will set the `checked` attribute on the **one** radiobutton whose value matches.

This behaviour will -in some way- conflict with setting the `[checked]` attribute: even if it is set on a radiobutton at creation, it will be reset as soon as the ngModel databinding gets in the way.

**Possible solution**

In your `AppComponent` class, double check that the `selectedCategory` member exists.
Then, set the `selectedCategory` property to the value of the selected category.

E.g., do something like this when you create (or receive) the categories:

```
for (let c of categories){
    if(c.checked){
        this.selectedValue = c._id;
        break;
    }
}
```

And, remove the `[checked]` binding from your markup. This sould suffice:

```
<label *ngFor="let cat of categories">
    <input 
       type="radio" 
       name="category" 
       [(ngModel)]="selectedCategory" 
       [value]="cat._id"/>
    {{ cat.label[lang.code] }}
</label>
```

Comment: That makes sense.. Thanks for you help Paolo!